# Differences between Cases and Position

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between `Cases` and `Position`.

What I want to do is to identify the elements of a (twice) nested list for which the first list contained in it itself contains a particular integer.
The following code correctly identifies these elements using "Cases"

```
snap = {{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {d, e, f}}};

Cases[snap, x_ /; MemberQ[x[[1]], 1]]
```

This correctly returns: `{{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}}`

I would have expected the following code to do essentially the same thing but to return the positions of these elements within "snap" rather than the elements themselves.

```
Position[snap, x_ /; MemberQ[x[[1]], 1]]
```

However this generates an error (multiple times before stopping):

> "Part specification List[[1]] is longer than depth of object."

Can someone explain why `Position` doesn't behave just like Cases? And is there an easy way to get the positions of the elements that match my pattern?

Thank you!

Comment: They have different default values of `Heads` option and default *levelspec*.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference between `Cases` and `Position` is obviously that the first one gives the matched expression, while the latter one gives the position of the expression. However, I'm sure you knew this. Kuba pointed out that the default level-spec differs as well. I want to point to something different.

I don't like your approach very much. `Cases` and `Position` take *patterns* and what you did is to use a pattern that matches everything and then you place a condition on the pattern. More severely, you use a condition that uses `[[1]]` which only works, if the match that is tested indeed has a first element!

This is not the case when the heads of your expressions (the heads are the symbol `List`) are tested. Therefore, to fix your call, you would need to do

```
Position[snap, x_ /; MemberQ[x[[1]], 1], {1}, Heads -> False]
(* {{1}} *)
```

If you have simple condition or test-function, you should rather use `Select` which is more appropriate

```
Select[snap, MemberQ[First[#], 1] &]
(* {{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}} *)
```

Or, we ignore the runtime for the moment, you can easily convert your *test function* into a real pattern:

```
Cases[snap, {{___, 1, ___}, _}]
(* {{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}} *)

Position[snap, {{___, 1, ___}, _}]
(* {{1}} *)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: As a follow-up (I hope I am not getting on your nerves with my lack of understanding): Is there a way to use "Position" in a way similar to your use of "Select"? I.e. how do I, in general, find the Position of elements that satisfy a certain condition. For example, suppose from a list of integers I want to find the positions of elements greater than 2:

Comment: Position[{1, 2, 3}, # > 2 &]

Comment: That doesn't work. My inelegant code does: Position[{1, 2, 3}, x_ /; x > 2]

Comment: Your code works for me, giving `{{3}}` as output which is correct. Again, you have the problem that `x_` catches every expression. Make the pattern *specific*! Like this: `Position[RandomInteger[10, {20}], x_Integer /; x > 2]`

Comment: @Christoph Ahh, sorry, now I see what you mean. `#>2&` is a testfunction, not a pattern. If you want to use `Position` it has to be a pattern. There are million ways with such toy examples. For instance `Position[Thread[{1, 2, 3} > 2], True]`. Or `Position[# > 2 & /@ {1, 2, 3}, True]`. Try to understand them to get a feeling for it.

Comment: beautiful. thanks again! I've learned a lot.